# Need to read only numeric values from a file and then sum them

Tags: python, import, pickle

I'm trying to read from a file and then find the sum of all numeric values. I keep getting a unsupported type error in line 19 and when I try to print the list I get a very weird output. The file is below and I need to only read numeric values.

The file

> q
>
> w
>
> e
>
> r
>
> t
>
> y
>
> u
>
> i
>
> o
>
> p
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5
>
> 6
>
> 7
>
> 8
>
> 9
>
> 0
>
> [
>
> ]
>
> ,
>
> .
>
> /
>
> 0.9
>
> 9.8
>
> 8.7
>
> 7.6
>
> 6.5
>
> 5.4
>
> 4.3
>
> 3.2
>
> 2.1
>
> 1.0

```
def sumOfInt():

with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:
    list = [map(float, line.split()) for line in infile]
    sumInt = sum(list)

print("The sum of the list isi:", sumInt)
```

Comment: Is that an example of the file contents?

Comment: what do you think `list = [map(float, line.split()) for line in infile]` does? cuz i doubt it does what you think it does

Comment: Sorry I just added the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def sumOfInt():

  with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:
      floatlist = []
      for line in infile:
          try:
              floatlist.append(float(line))
          except:
              pass
      sumInt = sum(floatlist)

      print("The sum of the list isi:", sumInt)
```

assuming that your input file onle has a simple string per line. this assesses whether the line can be converted to float or not, then appends that float onto the list.

Comment: This is my favorite answer. When you come back to it a year later, the logic will be immediately obvious.

Comment: error I am getting: line 24, in sumOfInt
    floatList.append(num)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'num' referenced before assignment

Comment: are you sure that line is inside of the else block?

Comment: I answered a little too quickly. I'd make that: `try: floatlist.append(float(line)); except: pass`. You can't have `else` without `except` in any version of Python I know.

Comment: Okay I updated with the else with except: pass but now im getting a type error in line 24 for sumInt = sum(list)

Comment: I think R Nar typo'ed: that's `sum(floatlist)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use regexp:

```
import re

with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:
    total = sum(map(float, re.findall("\d+.\d+|\d+", inifile.read())))
```

If you need list of all numeric values:

```
with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:    
    values = re.findall("\d+.\d+|\d+", inifile.read())
```

Comment: Okay I just added the file. Would that only select and read the numeric values?

Comment: I've updated answer to show how to retrieve numeric values.

Comment: stupid question, but where would I define infile? I'm getting a name error

Comment: @CiroCRiccardi in `with` block.

Answer (score 0):

ints were missing in my fist answer:

```
with open('data') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(sum([ float(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+.\d+|\d+|^.\d+', text)]))


# output:
94.5
```

Comment: This seems to work  but I should be getting 94.5 for the sum, not 49.5

Comment: @CiroCRiccardi I thought I saw only floats, but now fixed.

Comment: Okay great but could you please just refomat the code?

Comment: Thank you. Don't understand the downvotes, your answer was the only one that actually worked.

Comment: Just change your regexp to `\d+.\d+|\d+`, now it doesn't catch few digits integers.

Comment: That regexp matches "digit followed by anything followed by another digit". It also requires a leading 0, so valid floats like `.5` won't match.

Comment: Are you sure that `.5` is valid value?

Comment: It is according to Python, C, and all other languages I remember using. OP's inputs may not generate floats without leading zeros but he never said they were invalid. That regexp also matches `THIS IS NOT A NUMBER: 3.14 IS PIE` or any other embedded digits. Summary: it's probably a whole lot easier, faster, and less error prone to let Python parse built-in datatypes than to try to do it yourself with regexps.

Comment: `re.findall("\d+.\d+|\d+", "THIS IS NOT A NUMBER: 3.14 IS PIE")` returns `['3.14']`, and what you expect to retrieve?

Comment: Nothing, because "THIS IS NOT A NUMBER: 3.14 IS PIE" is not a valid float.

Comment: Seems like we talking about different things, at the beginning question was "How to retrieve numerical values" from text file.

Answer (score 0):

This is *almost* R Nar's answer:

```
def sumOfInt():
    with open("sample.txt", "r") as infile:
        total = 0
        for line in infile:
            try:
                total += float(line)
            except ValueError:
                pass

print("The sum of the list is:", total)
```

...the difference being that try/except is a little simpler and it doesn't build a (potentially huge) list of numbers before summing them.